# A fragment of Exercise 1.3.4 in _Shorter Model Theory_ by Hodges

Tags: logic, model-theory

The following is what I believe is necessary to solve Exercise 1.3.4 in *Shorter Model Theory* by Hodges.

Given two structure $\mathcal {A, B}$ of the same signature $\tau$, a set $S$ of generators of $\mathcal A$ and a map $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ (where $A, B$ are the domains of $\mathcal {A, B}$, resp.) such that for any *atomic* $\tau$-formula $\psi(\vec x)$  and any $\vec s \in S^n$ if $\mathcal A \models \phi(\vec s)$ then $\mathcal B \models \psi(\phi(\vec s))$, show that for any function symbol $f$, we have $f^{\mathcal B}(\phi(\vec s)) = \phi(f^{\mathcal A}(\vec s))$.

An obvious try is that replace $\phi(\dots)$ in the desired property with variables.  However, this doesn't work since $f^{\mathcal A}(\vec s)$ is not known to be in $S$.

How can I prove this?

EDIT: The precondition for $\psi$ should be that it is atomic.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It is not true, precisely because of the reason you stated. E.g. take $\mathcal B = \mathcal A$ and let $\phi$ be the identity on $S$. Then extend $\phi$ arbitrarily to $A$. Then $\phi$ satisfies the condition of your statement, but not the conclusion (in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mistake in Hodges. What is true (and a good exercise!) is that if $f$ is a partial map $A\to B$ defined on a set $S$ of generators for $A$, then $f$ can be extended to some homomorphism $A\to B$ if and only if it preserves atomic formulas (i.e. for $\overline{s}$ from $S$ and an atomic formula $\psi$, if $A\models \psi(\overline{s})$, then $B\models \psi(f(\overline{s})$).

Comment: Is such $f$ actually unique?

Comment: Yes, once you define $f$ on a set of generators for $A$, there is at most one homomorphism defined on all of $A$ extending it. You don't need anything about atomic formulas to prove that.

Comment: But the full text of **Exercise 1.3.4**, page 15 is : "$A,B$ are $L$-structures; $\overline a$ a sequence of elements which generates $A$ and $f : dom(A) \to dom(B)$. Show that $f$ is an *homomorphism* if and only for every atomic formula $\phi(\overline x)$ of $L$, if $A⊨\phi[\overline a]$, then $B⊨\psi[f(\overline a)]$." Why is wrong ? Thanks ...

Comment: It's wrong for the reason Levon Haykazyan gives in the comments. For a specific example, consider the map $f:(\mathbb{Z}_3,+) \to (\mathbb{Z}_3,+)$ given by sending everything to $1$. Now $1$ generates the structure, and $f(1) = 1$, so $f$ preserves atomic statements about $1$. But $f$ is clearly not a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

There is an errata for this available at http://wilfridhodges.co.uk/
It says: "For 'generate $A$' read 'lists the elements of $A$ ' ."

So, basically, $f^\mathcal{A}(\bar s)$ *is* known to be in $S$!

(On a side note, this may be the first time ever I have actually used the sequence '." in a text.)

Comment: For additional flavour, you can write it as «’.”». More to the point, it is kind of strange, it seems to significantly change the meaning of the exercise.

Comment: I figure it might just be a quick fix from Hodges' side.